# Azure Resources API Fields available for $filters & $expand

Tags: rest, azure, azure-resource-manager

`GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resources?$filter={$filter}&$expand={$expand}&$top={$top}&api-version=2018-02-01`

I'm using this Azure Resources API to get the list of resources (logic app connections) I need to know the field names available to use in $filter & $expand

from this I got the few field names like name, resourceType, tagname, location, resourceGroup

But I need to filter on **properties.displayname** field. I tried with $expand & $filter. its not working.

**Working with name $filter**

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resources?api-version=2018-02-01&$filter=(resourceGroup eq {resourcegroupname}) and **name eq {nametofilter}** and (resourcetype eq 'microsoft.web/connections')`

**Not working with displayname $filter with $expand**

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resources?$expand=ResourceProperties&api-version=2018-02-01&$filter=(resourceGroup eq {resourcegroupname}) and **ResourceProperties/displayName eq {nametofilter}** and (resourcetype eq 'microsoft.web/connections')`

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resources?$expand=Properties&api-version=2018-02-01&$filter=(resourceGroup eq {resourcegroupname}) and **Properties/displayName eq {nametofilter}** and (resourcetype eq 'microsoft.web/connections')`

Any suggestion to $filter with displayname field?

Comment: `Not working with displayname $filter with $expand` What error information about that? `Any suggestion to $filter with displayname field?` Based on my test, there is no `displayName` field if filter with `resourcetype eq 'microsoft.web/connections'`

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, if I use the `resourcetype eq microsoft.web/connections` to filter the resources. But there is no displayname field.

Based on my knowledge, if we want to use the $filter or $expand, we need to make sure that original result contains that fields.

[image]